# Share on Facebook, Retweet, etc, buttons in straight Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Notice those buttons atop http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/04/he-even-makes-coldplay-sound-fun/ for sharing the url on social networks?

I want to do something very very similar for a site I'm building. ShareThis offers a widget that does the same thing but it's branded and external.

I'm looking for a pure Ruby solution. A gem containing a module that could be included in a Rails ApplicationHelper class would be perfect.

Suggestions appreciated before I go reinventing the wheel!

imaginining something like:

```
<%= share_links object_url(@object), [:facebook, :twitter, :reddit] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

the best I can find is this: http://www.addthis.com/

there's a rails gem/plugin here: http://github.com/jaap3/addthis

and a tutorial at the wonderfully-named unitedelementsofhate.net - http://unitedelementsofhate.net/developers/addthis

from the looks of things, it's set up to work with rails 2.1, but I'm sure it won't take too much effort to get it running on 2.3.x or 3.0.beta....

hope this helps mate